# using ajax to get the values from database on form submit laravel

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel-5

I have a select list in my form like

```
 <form class="form-horizontal form-bordered" method="post" action="formaction">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="inputSuccess">Amount</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
           <select class="form-control mb-md" name="amount" id="amount">
                    <option value="10"> 10</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option value="30">30</option>
                    <option value="40">40</option>
                    <option value="50">50</option>
            </select>
        </div>

      <div class="input-group mb-md">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Submit</button>
      </div>
</form>

<script>
        $("#sub").click(function(){
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
            });


            var selectedVal= $("select option:selected").val();
            return $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'getdollarvalue',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: {
                    "value": selectedVal
                },
                success: function(response){

                   return alert(response);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And I have a table in database that stores corresponding values to selected dropdown values like

```
id      value         conversion
1         10            0.2
2         20            0.32
3         30            0.43
4         40            0.77
```

and so on

my `routes.php`

```
 Route::get('getdollarvalue/{value}', [
        'as' => 'getdollarvalue', 'uses' => 'dashboardController@getResult'
    ]);
```

and my `controller`

```
public function getResult(){
        $result = Input::get('value');

        return $result;
    }
```

Now, When I submit my form, I want to show the users in `alert` the corresponding value of the selected one. For example, If user selects `20` from the dropdown, then, on `submitting` the form, users is supposed to see the corresponding conversion of `20` i.e `0.32` in this case in alert. I know I have to implement `ajax` for this, I just don't understand how to implement it. Kindly guide me through this one.

Answer (score 1):

Html:

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-bordered" method="post" action="formaction">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="inputSuccess">Amount</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <select class="form-control mb-md" name="amount" id="amount">
                <option value="10"> 10</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="40">40</option>
                <option value="50">50</option>
        </select>
    </div>

  <div class="input-group mb-md">
       <button type="submit" id="sub" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Script:

```
<script>
$("#sub").click(function(){
var selectedVal= $("select option:selected").val();

   $.ajax({
       type:"GET",
       url: "api/URL",//put y
       data:{ val:selectedVal},
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "Json",
       success: function(result){
          alert(result.conversion); // Note Send the Json Object from the server side
       }

      });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I am not being able to post the selected dropdown value to my controller, how should I do that?

Comment: Please check the parameter which you are sending to the server , It should be same i.e { val:selectedVal}  the parameter 'val' should be present in the Model class which is about to receive  the call

Comment: I have updated my question please have a look and help me out of this.:)